# as3 Error 1009 at Coin1/coin1go(), i am trying to get an enemy to drop a coin

Tags: actionscript-3, null, typeerror, stage

So the enemy does drop a coin but i does not get the properties of the coin( if it hits the player it gives him +5 coins)

The coin will be removed if it hits the bottom of the stage, if the player dies or if the player hits it. Sadly, it does not work.

But this does work if i place a coin on the stage before i start the game, it gets all its properties, so then it must be the moment it gets added to the stage that it does not get linked with the coding or something..... and that is where i am right now.

this is the .as file for the coin:

package 
{

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
public class Coin1 extends MovieClip
{
    private var _root:Object;
    private var speed:int = 0;

    public function Coin1()
    {
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Speed1);
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, coin1go);
    }
    private function beginClass(event:Event):void
    {
        _root = MovieClip(root);
    }

    private function Speed1(event:Event):void
    {
        y +=  speed;
    }

        private function coin1go(event:Event):void
        {
        if (this.y > stage.stageHeight)
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, coin1go);
            _root.removeChild(this);
        }
        if (hitTestObject(_root.player_mc))
        {
            _root.coin +=  1;
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, coin1go);
            _root.removeChild(this);

        }
        if (_root.playerhealth <= 1)
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, coin1go);
            _root.removeChild(this);

        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the part from where it gets added to the stage:

```
    if (enemy2health <= 0)
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
        _root.score +=  _root.Enemy2Score * _root.scoremultiplyer;
        stage.addChild(newExplosionSmall)
        newExplosionSmall.x = this.x;
        newExplosionSmall.y = this.y;
        stage.addChild(newCoin1)
        newCoin1.x = this.x;
        newCoin1.y = this.y;
```

Ass you can see there is also an addchild for an explosion wich works perfectly fine but that may jus be because it does nothing else than appear and remove itself.

So long story short: enemy drops coin but it does nothing and floats to the bottom of the screen and i get a constant stream of 1009 errors. so does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should add an enterframe listener only after receiving a valid `stage` reference, which only appears when `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event is received. This is because your enterframe listener refers stage.

```
public function Coin1()
{
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Speed1);
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, beginClass);
}
private function beginClass(event:Event):void
{
    _root = MovieClip(root);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, coin1go);
}
```

Comment: Thnx, that solved the 1009 but now i get an 1034 error:
Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Stage@31077f99 to flash.display.MovieClip.
 at Coin1/beginClass()
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
 at flash.display::Stage/addChild()
 at Enemy_2/eFrame()

Comment: This means you don't have a "root" MovieClip but instead have Stage. Please trace "root" at `Enemy_2` class if there's a root, and add that coin not to the stage, but to the `_root` of enemy class.